# MySQL - Query three tables in one statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a query where it selects information using the following three tables and then combines the results in to one.

staff_members

```
s_id | name    |salary_id(fk)| dept_id (fk) |

1    |  John   |    3        |    2         |
2    |  Mike   |    3        |    5         |
3    |  Jen    |    3        |    1         |
4    |  Claire |    3        |    3         |
```

salaries

```
id   | salary |

1    | 28000  |
2    | 32000  |
3    | 34500  |
4    | 38000  |
```

bridge_team_staff

```
t_id (fk)| s_id (fk)|
  2      |    2     |
  3      |    1     |
  4      |    2     |
  1      |    3     |
  2      |    4     |
```

The bridge resolves a many to many relationship with teams and managers as a manager can have more than one team and a team can have more than one manager.

The query I want to run is to gather the manager's name, dept_id and the salary they're on based on their team_id in the bridge table.

For example, if I query the name, dept_id and salary of all staff members who are on team_id 2 it would show as below

```
name   | dept_id | salary |

Mike   |  2      | 34500  |
Claire |  3      | 34500  |
```

Comment: Shouldn't we have Mike instead of John in the results? John (`sid 1`) is mapped to `team_id 3`, while Mike (`sid 2`) is mapped to `team_id 2` (just like Claire).

Comment: yeah that's what i was thinking as well, unless there's a misunderstanding of how the bridge_table works

Comment: No you're both right, my bad.

Comment: in that case @izem's answer below is pretty much what I was going to suggest

Comment: though i wish i'd just posted it cause i could do with the upvotes haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understand correctly, you want a query like this:

```
SELECT m.name, m.dept_id, s.salary
FROM bridge_team_staff b
JOIN staff_members m ON(b.s_id = m.s_id)
JOIN salaries s ON(m.salary_id = s.id)
WHERE b.t_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, dept_id, salary
FROM staff_members JOIN
bridge_team_staff on s_id = s_id JOIN
salaries on salary_id = id
```